# YubiKey changed identity

Tags: yubikey

I unplugged my YubiKey und plugged it in a while later. When I try to login on websites using the hardware key I now get a popup from Chrome stating "the security key doesn't look familiar".

I can still use the authenticator with all added accounts. I can also decrypt my bitlocker encrypted thumb drives with the yubikeys certificate.

This suggests the key is the same and I haven't accidentally plugged in a second key.

How can the identity of the yubikey change? What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: You may want to contact [Yubico support](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us), not some random people on the interblogs.

Comment: It is entirely possible that something in Chrome, such as some authentication cookie, expired and was deleted. As a result your key just looks new to the program. The first step is to figure out if this is a real problem and as all your data and certificates are fine it appears not to be.

Comment: @mokubai The only problem is that I have to use a different authentication method to login now which fortunately is possible. In most cases I can remove and re-add the yubikey.